# Line return not displayed with gitlab CI

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a CI (git lab CI) which runs a shell that runs a makefile job, that calls bash scripts. The CI script is a YAML (gitlab-ci.yml) script.

**YAML script:**

```
Build:
  stage: ThisIsAnExample
  script: 
    - export OPTION1=true; make -C build/ myTarget
```

**Makefile script:**

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL = /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -ec

myTarget:
    @echo "A";echo ""; print "B\n";  echo "C";  echo "";
```

If I run the bash script from my console, I get:

```
A

B

C
```

On the CI log I get:

```
A
B
C
```

Why aren't the line returns interpreted by gitlab CI?

Comment: If your CI is a web application, there is a possibility that the output is not escaped/formatted properly, as all the whitespaces in html count as one. I would inspect the web source using browser's developer tools.

Comment: so i should do something like ```if runner=CI; then ESCAPE='\'; else ESCAPE=''; printf "A${ESCAPE}\nB${ESCAPE}\nC${ESCAPE}\n"```? My solution is quite ugly...any idea?

Comment: See also [blank lines in job log are not visible in web viewer (#217231) · Issues · GitLab.org / GitLab · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/217231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround.

I made those changes :

**in my YAML gitlab-ci script:**

```
Build:
  stage: ThisIsAnExample
  script: 
    - export OPTION1=true; export FORCE_LR_ESCAPE_IN_CI=yes; make -C build/ myTarget
```

**in my makefile:**

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL = /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -ec

FORCE_LR_ESCAPE_IN_CI ?= no

ifeq ($(FORCE_LR_ESCAPE_IN_CI),yes)
NEW_LINE = printf '\u2000\n'
else
NEW_LINE = echo ''
endif

myTarget:
    @echo "A"; $(NEW_LINE); echo "B"; $(NEW_LINE);  echo "C"; $(NEW_LINE);
```

I found that gitlab-ci skips a '\n' if it is not precessed by a character.
Looks like a bug to me. Anyway, I added an invisible character ('\u2000') before the '\n' and it works!

note: I tried with `echo '\u2000'` but it works only in the console, not in the ci.